# Replace particular axis with other value based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have original_image: as `(451, 521, 3)` shape.
And it contains [0,0,0] RGB values at some locations.

I would like to replace all `[0,0,0]` with `[0,255,0]`

What I tried was
I created mask which has `True` where `[0,0,0]` are located in `original_image`
And that mask has `(451, 521)` shape

I thought I could use following
`new_original_image=original_image[mask]`
But it turned out `new_original_image` is just an array (shape is like (18, 3)) whose all elements (for example, `[[ 97  68 108],[127  99 139],[156 130 170],...]`) are filtered by True of `mask` array from `original_image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
idx=np.all(np.vstack(a)==np.array([0,0,5]),1)
a1=np.vstack(a)
a1[idx]=[0,0,0]
yourary=a1.reshape(2,-1,3)
Out[150]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],
       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

---

Data input

```
a
Out[133]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 5]],
       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 5]]])
```

Comment: It's good idea that I deal with array in 2D than 3D with 1D mask array. I hope to write detailed code snippet (which I could implement based on your idea) in the reply.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to replace all [0,0,0] with [0,255,0]

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
rows, cols, channels = img.shape

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        if np.all(img[r,c][0]==[0,0,0]):
            img[r,c]=[0,255,0]
```

Comment: It's good idea and intuitive to replace axis value using `for loop`
Thanks for good solution. But you know even if it's working intuitively and well, 
since using `for loop` is rather slow, I hope to use NumPy in this task at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on reply solution from Wen-Ben, I try to write detailed code snippet that I wanted to implement

```
# original_image which contains [0,0,0] at several location 
# in 2 (last) axis from (451, 521, 3) shape image
# Stack original_image or using original_image.reshape((-1,3)) is also working
stacked=np.vstack(original_image)
# print(stacked.shape)
# (234971, 3)

# Create mask array which has True where [0,0,0] are located in stacked array
idx=np.all(stacked==[0,0,0],1)
# print(idxs.shape)
# (234971,)

# Replace existing values which are filtered by idx with [0,255,0]
stacked[idx]=[0,255,0]

# Back to original image shape
original_image_new=stacked.reshape(original_image.shape[0],original_image.shape[1],3)
# print(original_image_new.shape)
# (451, 521, 3)
```